# How to display the daily date in Telerik RadCalendar control

Tags: asp.net, telerik

i have use telerik calender control use in asp.net.i have click the calender control
and date are set near box but i want daily date automatically display... but i don't click  calender control ..Any ideas how I should code this?
i am beginner

Comment: Where to display the Daily Date? Please, describe it some briefly so that others can understand..

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're talking about?

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/calendar/examples/functionality/today/defaultcs.aspx

> Telerik RadCalendar can recognize and
>   mark Today's date. You should define a
>   RadCalendarDay object in the
>   SpecialDays collection, set its style
>   properties as required and then set
>   the Repeatable property to
>   RecurringEvents.Today.
>
> When using an embedded skin for
>   RadCalendar and the special day's
>   ItemStyle-CssClass="rcToday", the
>   skin's today style will be applied.

Comment: Thank you but i want  daily date display in automatically any idea any method

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the definition of "daily date".

Comment: Actually the customer the date click telerik calender control the today date are display but no click the calender control the date are display the daily date any  idea

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but the following JavaScript will select (not just highlight) today's date:

```
function SelectToday() {
    var todaysDate = new Date();
    var todayTriplet = [todaysDate.getFullYear(), todaysDate.getMonth() + 1, todaysDate.getDate()];
    var calendar = $find("<%=RadCalendar1.ClientID%>");
    calendar.selectDate(todayTriplet, true);
}
```

This can be executed on the [OnLoad](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/calendar-client-side-on-load.html) client-side event of the RadCalendar.